# Trying to get html response from apis in ionic

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework

I am calling linkedin api with passport-linkedin-oauth2 from nodejs. While I am calling it from postman I am getting the expected correct response (linkedin's login/signup page) in html format.

Now I am integrating this backend with ionic. When I am calling the api from my ionic app pages I get the response from linkedin in html format rather than in json. Thus I am storing the response in text format rather than json format.

After this I am getting lost. What do I do after this?

I am thinking I will convert the response from text into html and then somehow display it.

EDIT: So I got the response on the display page as text. Its in the variable ***name*** in the .ts page.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage{
  name: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.name = navParams.get('name');
```

Now I am trying to display it in in html format using

```
<div [innerHtml]="name">{{name}}</div>
```

But I get it in text format and not html. How to display in html format?

Comment: you can display html using `innerHtml` in a tag like `<div [innerHtml]="response"></div>`

Comment: Am i trying it the wrong way? @NRaghavendra

Comment: you need not enter `{{name}}` just `<div [innerHtml]="name"></div>` is fine

Comment: I tried <div [innerHtml]="name"></div> but its the same thing.

Comment: just for clarification, do you wish to see content along with html tags or content to be rendered as html content inside div? for second case if you have any unsafe styling or content angular will simply convert it, simply use angular dom sanitizer

Comment: Yes I used the dom saniizer. That helped. :)